# Getting "The Application Default Credentials are not available" error in android studio even though env variable is set

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-vision

I'm currently having an issue in android studio. I have set my Google app credentials environment variable AND restarted android studio over and over and its giving me the same error.

I know I am using the correct service account `JSON` file for my app and I know the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable is set (The variable shows up in my android studio terminal AND my computer's terminal), I just have no clue why this isn't working.

Also even though the variable is set, when I do 
`"System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATON_CREDENTIALS")"` it returns *null*. I don't knwo why this is either.

Here is the line of code throwing this **error**:

> GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault().fromStream(credentialsJSON).createScoped(VisionScopes.all());

My `credentialsJSON` comes from this line of code:

```
InputStream credentialsJSON = LabelApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("C:\\[path-to-service-acct-json]");
```

Comment: put the service account file in the class path for the app. How will the app find the resource file when inside a mobile phone? put it in the app/src/main/java folder

Comment: @Kushan service-account credentials are not meant to be put into resources.

Comment: yep agreed, i mentioned that in my answer

Comment: Your phone doesn't have `C:\\[path-to-service-acct-json]`. Simple

Comment: So how do I make my "C:\path" have a place in my smartphone? @Zun

Comment: You aren't supposed to use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in an app. Could you tell me what you're building?

Comment: I'm building an app that uses Google Could Vision API. Is that what you're asking? @Zun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just set `GOOGLE_APPLICATON_CREDENTIALS` on your PC and expect them to be known on your smartphone... for Android (which does not equal Java), better use the [ML Kit for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/).

See the [ML Kit for Firebase Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) Android application.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. What exactly do I do with ML Kit for Firebase in relation to my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? Like where does it come in, in relation to my Google Cloud Vision implementation? This is the first time I'm hearing of "ML Kit"

Comment: @MaryAshleyEtefia you'd likely need to add key fingerprints and then download a `google-services.json` on the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and also setup the Play Services plugin, so that the Android application can authenticate; for Android it's a different account-type than the credentials for desktop/server Java applications (because these string resources can easily be extracted from the APK package).

Answer (score 0):

How will the app find the resource file when inside a mobile phone? put it in the app/src/

put the file is in your classpath e.g. put the file in "src" folder, and make sure its moved in "bin" or "classes" folder after compilation:

```
URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
String fileName = fileURL.getFile();
String filePath = fileURL.getPath();
```

Also do note that doing this will work, but is extremely insecure and should not be done in production. Service account file is a critical file and should not be exposed. So i suggest you do whatever you need to do from your server side code instead of doing this

Comment: as stated in the other answer, i suggest you use ML kit from firebase and use Firebase Auth library for the login/authentication instead of doing what you are trying to do

Comment: Does using ML Kit mean I don't have to use the Google Cloud Vision API? This is my first time hearing about it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Google Could Vision API in an Android app. Instead, use ML Kit for Firebase.

to quote their docs:

> Mobile platform examples
>
> These sample apps show how you can easily use the Cloud Vision label
> detection, landmark detection, and text recognition APIs from your
> mobile apps with ML Kit for Firebase. ML Kit also provides APIs to
> perform face detection, barcode scanning, inference using custom ML
> models, and more, all on the device, without requiring a network call.

and see https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit